# Create a dependent dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a dependent dropdown list in col L, based on the chosen in the dropdown list in col K

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("L2:L" & lastRow)
        ' Clear existing data validation
        cell.Validation.Delete
        
        ' Apply data validation to the cell in column L
        With cell.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address & ", "" "", ""_""))"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
            .InputTitle = "Select an Item" ' Set your default message here
        End With
    Next cell
```

I was able to create the dependent dropdown lists manually using the "=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(K2," ","_"))" formula in the Source field. But Now I'm trying to create this in VBA.
I created Named Ranges to carry on this process and used INDIRECT formula to call the named range when the value is selected in K2.

When I run the script, everything works till it reaches

```
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
 xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address & ", "" "", ""_""))"
```

I get the error
"runtime error 91
object variable or with block variable not set"

Here I'm trying to apply the dropdown list in col L and refer to the value in respective cell in col K by using the Offset function. Could someone tell me what wrong in the script ?

Answer (score 1):

The operator should probably be xlEqual instead of xlBetween.

Also, instead of using formulas, I use strings that are either hard-coded or that I stitch together from lists in worksheets.  Doing it this way seems to have eliminated the errors that I used to get years ago.

```
Dim s As String, Delim As String
Dim Rng As Range

For Each Rng In MyRange
    s = s & Delim & Rng.Text
    Delim = ","
Next
    
Formula1:= s
```

Comment: Using hard-coded strings for the list has a fairly low upper limit on the length of the string...

Answer (score 0):

I think that `INDIRECT()` is evaluating to an error if there's no value selected in Col K, and that's causing the `.Add` to raise the error. If you put a valid value in Col K it should work.

You'll see the issue if you try to set up the DV list manually with no ColK value - you will get "The source currently evaluates to an error.  Do you want to continue?"

I was getting Error 1004 though, not 91.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim rngVal As Range, f As String, ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, cell As Range

    '...
    '...
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = 10 'for example
    Set rngVal = ws.Range("L2:L" & lastRow)
    rngVal.Validation.Delete 'remove any existing validation
    
    rngVal.Offset(0, -1).Value = "BLAH BLAH" 'prevent error on adding DV formula
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each cell In rngVal.Cells
        'create the formula
        f = "=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address & _
                            ","" "",""_""))"
        
        With cell.Validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=f
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
            .InputTitle = "Select an Item" ' Set your default message here
        End With
    Next cell
    
    rngVal.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents 'clear values from Col K
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: updated with full working code.  I have a named range `BLAH_BLAH` on the worksheet `ws`

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work but you were right, I did get error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Did you replace "some valid value" with a valid selection from the Column K dropdown?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I don't think OP's formula parse is correct.

Comment: It works for me - I assume they mean to replace spaces in the ColK value to form a valid range name to use as the source for the DV drop down in Col L.

Comment: @TimWilliams, yeah, I suspect OP doesn't have a space after the comma.

Comment: There's no space needed there?  If you mean inside the formula string.

Comment: The formula in OP's question doesn't have a comma than space in the 'old text' field: `"=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(K2," ","_"))"` but Op's parsing has one.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes I changed the value in col K to be a valid choice. Also, to give a bit more context, I'm working in MS Access VBA. It seems have some limitations when declaring `As Range` or `As Worksheet` so for all such declarations are made `As Object`. 
`& cell.Offset(0, -1).Address &`  the cell used here is declared `As Object`

Comment: So have you added a reference to the Excel object model in your Access VBA project?  Otherwise it has no idea what the values of those Excel constants such as `xlValidateList` might be, and will default them to zero.  If you use `Option Explicit` you'll get warnings about that.

Comment: ...if you do have a reference you can `Dim cell As Excel.Range`, `Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet` etc

Comment: whats confusing is, I've inserted a dropdown list usingin the same method in col k  and that worked but it uses a list in `formula1` option and cos I thought thought the issue must be with the string formula I used. In the previous dropdown list I used `xlValidateList`  and `xlBetween` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your parsing of the formula is correct. It doesn't match the formula you've put in your question.

If you're interested, I generally create a string of the formula and try writing that to a blank cell in my sheet to see if it works or looks as I want it. Here's some sample code of that, together with a possible correction to your parsed formula. I wasn't sure if you wanted to space after the comma, so add it in if you need it:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim yourFormula As String, goodFormula As String

Set cell = Sheet1.Range("C1")
yourFormula = "=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address & ", "" "", ""_""))"
goodFormula = "=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(" & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address & ","","",""_""))"
Sheet1.Range("D1").Formula = yourFormula
Sheet1.Range("E1").Formula = goodFormula
With cell.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=goodFormula
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: OP wants to replace spaces with underscores though?

Comment: yes I do need the space there since the choices have spaces in between words but the named ranges (derived from these choices) do not have spaces but they have underscores.